# wso2 identity server SAML artifact binding - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: wso2, saml, artifact, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to configure an application to make use of SAML artifact binding using wso2 identity server.

I generated the following XML to be sent to localhost:9443/samlartresolve

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<samlp:ArtifactResolve 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
    ID="_ccce23e3-f583-4e5c-bf4f-25fb4b430482"
    IssueInstant="2019-05-02T15:08:10Z">
<Issuer>localhost</Issuer>
<Artifact>AAQAADNDiQSLhypTMAKzTXP4wp/QnvxQqZvtgNuXaUtcojeNQm1wfAkJGAM=</Artifact>
</samlp:ArtifactResolve>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but am receiving a 500 error. When checking the logs I see that I get the following error server side

```
[2019-05-02 16:22:38,208] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve} -  Servlet.service() for servlet [bri
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLArtifactResolveServlet.handleArtifact(SAMLArtifactResolveSer
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLArtifactResolveServlet.handleRequest(SAMLArtifactResolveServ
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLArtifactResolveServlet.doPost(SAMLArtifactResolveServlet.jav
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:72)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.j
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the IS version you are trying ?

Comment: wso2 is Version 5.7.0